# Why qsort cause error in gcc 6.3.0 by using typedef enum?

Tags: c, typedef, gcc-warning, qsort

I'm working for Strongly Connected Component (SCC) algorithm.

So, I sorted vertices by increasing order using `qsort` function.

To use `qsort`, I made my own compare function and used `typedef enum{false,true} bool`.

VS2017 IDE compiles successfully of this but MinGW which has gcc 6.3.0 cause error like below.

[image]

My `CreateSorted` and `qsort` compare function are these codes.

```
// qsort compare function, descending order
bool cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    VF* vf1 = (VF*)p1;
    VF* vf2 = (VF*)p2;
    return vf2->f - vf1->f;
}

// Create sorted vertices array of VF structure
// For DFS of decreasing finish time vertex
VF* CreateSorted(adjList* adj)
{
    VF *sorted_vertices = (VF*)malloc(sizeof(VF)*(adj->vertexNum+1));

    for (int i = 1; i <= adj->vertexNum; i++) {
        Node* current = adj[i].nodeList;
        sorted_vertices[i].v = current->v;
        sorted_vertices[i].f = current->f;
    }
    qsort(sorted_vertices+1, adj->vertexNum, sizeof(VF), cmp);
    return sorted_vertices;
}
```

What I really curious is the reason of error resulting from `typedef enum{false, true} bool`.

Comment: The answer is correct. But, your `cmp` function is also just wrong, since you are declaring it to return `true` and `false`, when the function is returning a value that may be less than `0`, greater than `0`, or equal to `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fourth parameter to `qsort` should be a pointer to a function with the following prototype:

`int compar (const void* p1, const void* p2)`

The prototype of your function is:

`bool compar (const void* p1, const void* p2)`